# String manipulation in C# to increment a number

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm using .net 2.0 and I have the following string

```
string 1 = "test (10)"
```

I have a regular expression that strips the number 10 from the string, I then want to increment it and insert this into the parenthesis of the previous string to create a new strings so:

```
string 2 = "something else(11)"
```

Comment: Could we see your regular expression?

Comment: So covnert the stripped 10 to int, increment them replace previous number with new number?

Answer (score 2):

If the string is always going to have the same format, you can do it like this:

```
int myNumber = 11;
string two = String.Format("test ({0})", myNumber);
```

This is assuming you already have the RegExp as you say in your question, and have incremented it by 1.

**EDIT**

New example according to your new information:

```
int myNumber = 11;
int myNewString = "Test";
string two = String.Format("{0} ({1})", myNewString, myNumber);
```

Comment: the string might not be test always but it will be followed by parenthesis with a number inside of it...

Comment: But I guess at the time of creation you know what the string will be (it would be hard to create the string otherwise), so I would keep the same kind of logic. See my updated example. No reason to use any "magic" here. Keep it simple ;)

Comment: This is not necessarily the case. What if his task is to increment every number enclosed in paranthesis in a string that is user input?

Comment: If he decides the string himself, or it's a user inputed string does not really matter. At the time the string number two is generated the string will be known even if a user inputed it. My point is that at if the string is not known at the time of generation, you can't generate it since you do not have knowledge about the string to generate.

Comment: @Stilgar - In your answer, you need the input into the RegEx as well, so you will also need prior knowledge of the string to generate.

Comment: You are right I missed the part where he changes the content before the number and thought it would be the same. Deleting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do ... but KEEP IT SIMPLE

```
var value = ExtractValue(str1);
value++;
string str2 = "test (" + value + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let a Class handle it..something like this.

TestNumbers testNumbers = new TestNumbers(1);
 testNumbers.Increment(1);
 testNumbers.GetNumber();
 testNumbers.ToString();

```
    public class TestNumbers
    {
        private int number = 0;

        public TestNumbers(int number)
        {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Test (" + number + ")";
        }

        public void Increment(int incrementStep)
        {
            number += incrementStep;
        }

        public int GetNumber()
        {
            return number;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you do with following code:

```
String s1 = string.format("{0} ({1})",yourstring,value);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `regex` solution might be:

```
string inputString = "test (10)";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.+)\((?<Digit>\d+)\)");
Match match = regex.Match(inputString);

int i = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["Digit"].Value);
i++;

string replacePattern = "$1(" + i + ")";
string newString = regex.Replace(inputString, replacePattern);

Console.WriteLine(newString);
```